# Why I am having duplicate values displaying all over again when I use my onlick event?

Tags: php, jquery

here my js script

```
<script>
    function displayWarriors() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "display_warriors.php",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#tableWarrior").append(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
    function createWarrior() {
        $.post( "create_warrior.php", { 
        "wname": $("#txtWname").val(),
        "wtype": $("#txtWtype").val()           
        }, 
        function(msg){
            displayWarriors();
        });
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

and I use this line of html code when firing the function from my event

```
<input onclick="return createWarrior()"
```

for example I have No.1 Name1 displayed on my table, then I add another like Name 2

My output goes

```
No.1 Name1
No.1 Name1
No.2 Name2
```

How can I fix this

my display_warriors.php

```
foreach($stmt as $warrior){
        echo '<tr><td>'.$warrior['warrior_id'].'</td><td><a href="selected.php?id='.$warrior['warrior_id'].'">'.$warrior['warrior_name'].'</a></td><td>'.$warrior['warrior_type'].'</td></tr>';
    }
```

Comment: what is the contents of `display_warriors.php`?

Answer (score 3):

Duplicates are coming, because you always returning all data, in which some are already present in 'tableWarrior' element, You should change the statement

```
success: function(data) {
       $("#tableWarrior").append(data);
}
```

to

```
success: function(data) {
       $("#tableWarrior").empty();
       $("#tableWarrior").append(data);
}
```

You should change

```
<script>
    function displayWarriors(wname, wtype) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "display_warriors.php",
            data: { name: wname, type: wtype},
            success: function(data) {
                $("#tableWarrior").append(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
    function createWarrior() {
        var name =  $("#txtWname").val(),
        var type =  $("#txtWtype").val()   

        $.post( "create_warrior.php", { 
        "wname": name,
        "wtype": type           
        }, 
        function(msg){
            displayWarriors(name, type);
        });
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

and your display_warrior.php, should return a single warrior tr. like

```
$name = $_REQUEST["name"];
$type = $_REQUEST["type"]
$warrior = GetYourWarriorWithItsNameAndType($name, $type);//Call a funciton here to get the warrior from its name and type.

echo '<tr><td>'.$warrior['warrior_id'].'</td><td><a href="selected.php?id='.$warrior['warrior_id'].'">'.$warrior['warrior_name'].'</a></td><td>'.$warrior['warrior_type'].'</td></tr>';
```

Comment: it destroys my table and the output is still the same

Comment: @BrainedWashed, is display_warriors.php page have only this statement `echo '<tr><td>'.$warrior['warrior_id'].'</td><td><a href="selected.php?id='.$warrior['warrior_id'].'">'.$warrior['warrior_name'].'</a></td><td>'.$warrior['warrior_type'].'</td></tr>';
`

Comment: @BrainedWashed, than how are you making and passing `$warrior` in this file?

Comment: @BrainedWashed, as you are looping, it will return multiple `tr` from display_warriors.php file, so it is returning duplicates also.

Comment: Updated the answer, Might It fix your issue. Good Luck :)